# Failed to Save XGBoost Model in EMR 6.7

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, xgboost

I am trying to train an Xgboost model in EMR 6.7 and save the model to S3 (Xgboost version is 1.3.1 and Spark version is 3.2.1). But when saving the model this error occurs: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.JsonDSL$.pair2Assoc(Lscala/Tuple2;Lscala/Function1;)Lorg/json4s/JsonDSL$JsonAssoc;`

I've tried the higher versions of xgboost but there was error while training.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier

val data = Seq((9,1),(8,1),(8,1),(7,1),(8,0),(2,0),(1,0),(3,0))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val df_train = rdd.toDF("input","label")

val stringIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label").setOutputCol("labelIndex").fit(df_train)
val labelTransformed = stringIndexer.transform(df_train).drop("label")
val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("input")).setOutputCol("features_vector")

val xgbInput = vectorAssembler.transform(labelTransformed).select("features_vector", "labelIndex")

val xgbParam = Map("eta" -> 0.1f,
     "max_depth" -> 2,
     "objective" -> "multi:softprob",
     "num_class" -> 2,
     "num_round" -> 100,
     "num_workers" -> 2)
val xgbClassifier = new XGBoostClassifier(xgbParam).
     setFeaturesCol("features_vector").
     setLabelCol("labelIndex")
val xgbClassificationModel = xgbClassifier.fit(xgbInput)

xgbClassificationModel.write.overwrite().save("path")
```

Can you help me about that please?

Comment: Are you using sbt?

Comment: No i am not using sbt. But i get the similar errors when i use sbt.